# Z Index - Sliding transitions overlapping is there a way to create a dynamic z index?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I've been laboring over this for days.  I have been teaching myself CSS so be nice to the noob.  I am creating a testimonial slider.  Testimonials are displayed in blocks of 3.  I would like the top 2 to downslide and the 3rd to upslide.  But the desc div for the 3rd testimonial still appears below the others when the slider activates no matter what I do to the Z index in the hover.  Also note I am embedding this in a Wix website (yes, yes, I know) that is why I am not using a sep style sheet.

Please help.  Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.Holt{
position: relative;
z-index: 9;
background-image:url("http://static.wix.com/media/2235b3_e3148abc7ee042adb94751efb211bd81.png_850");
width:777px;
height:116px;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.Holt:hover{
background-image:url("http://static.wix.com/media/2235b3_083d120266e44626aef3a13fc9d9571d.png_850");
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-o-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-ms- box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-transform: scale(1.01, 1.01);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.01, 1.01);
-ms-transform: scale(1.01, 1.01);
-o-transform: scale(1.01, 1.01);
transform: scale(1.01, 1.01);
}

.Holt div.desc{ 
position: absolute;
width: 99.5%;
z-index: 8; 
bottom: 0;
left: 0px;
padding: 2px;
text-align:justify;
line-height:119%;
background: rgba(231, 232, 232, .9);
color:#060404;
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
-o-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
-ms-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
opacity: 0;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}

.Holt div.desc a{
color: white;
}

.Holt:hover div.desc{
-moz-transform: translate(0, 100%);
-webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%);
-ms-transform: translate(0, 100%);
-o-transform: translate(0, 100%);
transform: translate(0, 100%);
opacity:1;
}

.Rose{
position: relative;
z-index: 7;
background-image:url("http://static.wix.com/media/2235b3_3598323284184651bf79a10568aa5333.png_1024");
width:777px;
height:116px;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.Rose:hover{
background-image:url ("http://static.wix.com/media/2235b3_b9f759cc6e644d90bf91184f33747129.png_850");
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-o-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-ms- box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-transform: scale(1.01, 1.01);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.01, 1.01);
-ms-transform: scale(1.01, 1.01);
-o-transform: scale(1.01, 1.01);
transform: scale(1.01, 1.01);
}

.Rose div.desc{
position: absolute;
width: 99.5%;
z-index: 6;
bottom: 0;
left: 0px;
padding: 2px;
text-align:justify;
line-height:119%;
background: rgba(231, 232, 232, .9);
color:#060404;
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
-o-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
-ms-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
opacity: 0;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}

.Rose div.desc a{
color: white;
}

.Rose:hover div.desc{
-moz-transform: translate(0, 100%);
-webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%);
-ms-transform: translate(0, 100%);
-o-transform: translate(0, 100%);
transform: translate(0, 100%);
opacity:1;
}

.Crozat{
position: relative;
z-index: 5;
background-image:url("http://static.wix.com/media/2235b3_4adb40821e3b4737a40bd070f147ed4a.png_850");
width:777px;
height:116px;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.Crozat:hover{
background-image:url("http://static.wix.com/media/2235b3_a45ada8a12654b17a3fd22f0c987a6f5.png_850");
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-o-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-ms- box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-transform: scale(1.01, 1.01);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.01, 1.01);
-ms-transform: scale(1.01, 1.01);
-o-transform: scale(1.01, 1.01);
transform: scale(1.01, 1.01);
}

.Crozat div.desc{
position: absolute;
width: 99.5%;
z-index: 4;
top: 0;
bottom: auto;
left: 0px;
padding: 2px;
text-align:justify;
line-height:119%;
background: rgba(231, 232, 232, .9);
color:#060404;
-moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
-o-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
-ms-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
opacity: 0;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}

.Crozat div.desc a{
color: white;
}

.Crozat:hover div.desc{

-moz-transform: translate(0, -100%);
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -100%);
-ms-transform: translate(0, -100%);
-o-transform: translate(0, -100%);
transform: translate(0, -100%);
opacity:1;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="Holt">
<div class="desc">
<p style="margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;font-family:arial; font-size:13px;">“I am grateful
to have had the opportunity to experience Warren’s insight, grace, boldness and heart over the
last several years all of which have served me personally and professionally. The skills that he
personifies not only in his coaching and training but in his daily life have inspired me to make
many successful changes in my communications, clarifying current challenges and solutions, and
supporting me to the see the other side of some difficult issues.  I heartily recommend Warren
if you want to go to the next level in your life or profession.”
<p style="color:#2a4451; margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;line-height:108%;font-family:arial; 
font-size:13px;padding:0; margin-bottom: 0;">William DB Holt
<p style="color:#c7c7c7; margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;line-height:108%;font-family:arial;
font-size:13px;padding:0;margin-top: 0">Partner
<br><a href="http://www.trivergentinternational.com/TrivVergent_International%
3A_Optimizing_Human_Capital/Video_Introduction.html" target="_blank">Trivergent 
International</a> <br>
</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="Rose">
<div class="desc">
<p style="margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;font-family:arial; font-size:13px;">"Warren seems
to get at the root of what is slowing or blocking my ability to move forward in my life business
wise and personal. His coaching has increased my success dramatically."
<p style="color:#2a4451; margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;line-height:108%;font-family:arial;
font-size:13px;padding:0; margin-bottom: 0;">Jeff Rose
<p style="color:#c7c7c7; margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;line-height:108%;font-family:arial;
font-size:13px;padding:0;margin-top: 0">Principal
<br><a href="http://www.mcgillengineers.com/" target="_blank">McGill Associates Engineering</a>  
<br>
</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="Crozat">
<div class="desc">
<p style="margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;font-family:arial; font-size:13px;">"Warren seems
to get at the root of what is slowing or blocking my ability to move forward in my life business 
wise and personal. His coaching has increased my success dramatically."
<p style="color:#2a4451; margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;line-height:108%;font-family:arial;
font-size:13px;padding:0; margin-bottom: 0;">Jeff Rose
<p style="color:#c7c7c7; margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;line-height:108%;font-family:arial;
font-size:13px;padding:0;margin-top: 0">Principal
<br><a href="http://www.mcgillengineers.com/" target="_blank">McGill Associates Engineering</a> 
<br>
</p>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can share the images/screenshots of the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you may need to change the `z-index` for main divs on `:hover` :

- First remove the `z-index` values for `.Holt` - `.Rose` and `.Crozat`

  ```
  .Crozat{
     position: relative;
     /*z-index: 5; Remove this*/
  ```
- Second add this on the CSS:

  ```
  .Holt:hover, .Rose:hover, .Crozat:hover {
     z-index:1;
  }
  ```

Here you can see a demo with your code **http://jsfiddle.net/LGCNx/3/**